# Grayed out "Redirect" option in OSX Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, menu-bar

Running recent Mavericks (10.9.5)

I am wondering why I can only sometimes redirect messages, as opposed to forwarding, as in principle being offered via "Message > Redirect".

Sometimes this works, sometimes not, i.e., "Message > Redirect" is a grayed out option.

Ts there a somewhere documented pattern for this behaviour?

Comment: Need more info like what email provider ect..I just checked my 10.9.5 with gmail and windows live mail and redirect is always there.

Comment: What is the difference between emails when the redirect works and when it not. Are they encrypted or not, are they market urgent, private ect.. Are the from same email server/provider.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the email server provider. It looks like all of the impossibles are from my work accounts. There are two of them, one is Exchange-based, the other is not (IMAP). Redirect seems to work for none of Exchange, but some of the IMAP. In those cases, where it does not work for IMAP from within Apple Mail, I could still properly redirect (visible also in the headers at the receiving end) when using the Horde-based Web-frontend. Other than this, I have not yet been able to find any further patterns.

Comment: Thanks...this might be complicated but you can try. Move emails to "On my Mac", then use redirect.

Comment: Not complicated ... I chose one of the IMAP-messages that Apple Mail could not Redirecet, while Horde could, and moved it to a Test-folder "On My Mac". Apple Mail was still uncapable of Redirect-ing.

Comment: sorry, I am fresh out of my wisdom :)

Answer (score 1):

Redirect is [disabled for Exchange accounts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19148) (last §), presumably because the sender address is enforced by the Exchange server (to prevent [spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing)).